# FBO depth texture in OpenGL 2.1+

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm curently learning to create shadown using GLSL but I have some troubles here:
1. In GLSL 3.3, we can use this statement in fragment shader:

```
layout(location = 0) out float fragmentdepth;
```

to write only depth 16bit out to texture (setted as `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16` before) but how can I do some thing like that in OpenGL 2.1 (GLSL 1.20)?

1. As far as I know, for rendering depth buffer, we only need change the camera position to light position and camera direction to light direction and changed back if we are drawing real scene, Is it right?

Comment: I think you should attach depth buffer to an fbo, and render to `gl_FragDepth`; I'm not sure if you won't need an extension for that.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: I have used glew in my projects, thanks you, i'll try `gl_FragDepth` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In GLSL 3.3, we can use this statement in fragment shader:
>
> to write only depth 16bit out to texture (setted as GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16 before)

No, you can't.

That will set `fragmentdepth` to write to a *color buffer*. And you cannot attach an image with the `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16` [image format](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format) to [a `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTi` attachment point of an FBO](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Framebuffer_Object_Structure). Attempting to do so will [give you a `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT` error](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Attachment_Completeness).

In *all* versions of GLSL, the only way to write to the attached depth buffer is to write to `gl_FragDepth`. And in *all* versions of GLSL, you can only have one depth buffer attached to the FBO. Though [Image Load/Store](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store) does allow you to work around that, but you lose depth testing and such.

Comment: Thanks you very much, I based on this article: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-16-shadow-mapping/ but seem my understand is wrong (The link have broken yesterday, so, i post it's cache)

Comment: Yeap, I got it, depth value is auto write during the pipeline :D

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/164387-Are-EXT-s-necessary-for-FBO-use-in-OpenGL-2-1) you need to use FBO extension (EXT) if targeting OpenGL 2.1.Also why on earth are you still using fixed pipeline?It is deprecated .If your hardware allows you - use OpenGL 3.3+ and then leverage (core) FBOs with texture attachments (or renderbuffers) to which you can draw depth buffer data.Yes,you can still do the same with the deprecated profile but well,the modern OpenGL made a huge step forward since then.

Anyways , [here](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/163855-Render-to-depth-texture) is what you need for your version.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I only own a Intel GMA 945 graphic card which supported OpenGL 2.1 but I'm reading OpenGL 3.3 tutorial, LOL. Thanks for your links, it seem very useful for me :D

Comment: OpenGL 2.1 is **not** necessarily fixed-function. It hasn't deprecated it, but it supports modern OpenGL as well.